# Script rotate the object more than I need

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player, which I rotate using script below. It rotate player on 20 degree, not 10 (and I need 10). Can't understand why. When I press `q`, it executes only 1 time.

[image]

[image]

```
private UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController firstPersonController;
public GameObject player;

void Start ()
{ 
    firstPersonController = player.GetComponent<UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController>();
}

void Update ()
{
    StartCoroutine("RotatePlayerDelay");        
}

IEnumerator RotatePlayerDelay()
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    firstPersonController.m_MouseLook.myAngle += 10; // here I have +20, not +10
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.005f);
    firstPersonController.m_MouseLook.myAngle = 0;
    Debug.Log("2");
}
```

P.S. I need coroutine, because without it it will be rotate forever

Comment: It's somewhat hard to give an answer without knowing the FirstPersonController class nor the MouseLook class. I'm also pretty sure you don't need a coroutine for that but rather a boolean like "isAiming" or "isFacingTarget". By the way: the coroutine is started every frame which doesn't seem desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `FixedUpdate` which is called once every `Time.fixedDeltaTime` seconds, there is no exact time step for `Update` method. It is a coroutine which depends on FPS of the game and duration of all the renderers and behaviours and thus dynamically changes.

You can think of `Update` as:

```
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(_update);        
}
IEnumerator _update()
{
    while(true)
    {
         Update();
         yield return null;             
    }
}
```

When you start your coroutine in `Update` method you can't tell whether or not the previous frame has ended or not. If your FPS is lower than `1/0.005 = 200.0 FPS` the different calls of the coroutine surely overlap with each other.

*0.005 here refers to yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.005f)*

---

Try **not to** start the coroutine in another coroutine:

```
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine("RotatePlayerDelay");        
}

IEnumerator RotatePlayerDelay()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
        firstPersonController.m_MouseLook.myAngle += 10; // here I have +20, not +10
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.005f);
        firstPersonController.m_MouseLook.myAngle = 0;
        Debug.Log("2");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.005f);
    }
}
```